# Print ClientDataSet without consultation with the reporting component

Tags: delphi

Preferably FastReport, but can be any that you know. I just ZConnection and ZQuery to work with the database. When I need to feed a grid with data from the database, do the power on hand, without using ClientDataSet. Does anyone know how I could feed a report without turning it into components database?

Comment: No one forces you to use `TClientDataSet`. For FastReport example of how to make a report with no DB relation check the `Demos` folder (e.g. the `PrintFile` or `PrintStringList` demos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastReport supports a wide variety of databases and datasources. You don't need to connect it to a `TClientDataset` to use it. From the wording of your question, it sounds like you need to make use of the `TfrxUserDataset`. This allows you to drive a report from any source (Listview, StringGrid, ObjectList etc).

You provide data via `TfrxUserDataset`'s `OnGetFieldValue` event. You will also need to provide a `RecordCount` value and a `OnCheckEOF` event. As TLama pointed out, there are demonstration programs on how to do this in `FastReport`'s `Demos` folder.